# deleting rows that have same date time

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get only row with the same minute? the seconds value do no matter. It seem like the row can be deleted using something like `df.drop(index=2)`, but the data are so many to be deleted one over one.

```
import json
import math
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd
a=open(r'C:\work\kenkyuu\FITBIT\MyFitbitData (4)\AswadMdnor\user-site-export\heart_rate-2019-11- 
17.json')
b=json.load(a)
df = json_normalize(b)
df = df.rename(columns={'value.bpm':'bpm','value.confidence':'confidence'})
print(df)

    dateTime           bpm           confidence
11/17/19 02:28:05  113           0
11/17/19 02:28:17   70           0
11/17/19 02:28:31   70           0
11/17/19 02:28:42   70           0
11/17/19 02:29:29   70           0
11/17/19 02:29:46   70           0
11/17/19 02:30:43   70           0
11/17/19 02:32:13   70           0
11/17/19 02:49:39   70           0
```

i hope for this output:

```
dateTime           bpm           confidence
11/17/19 02:28:05  113           0
11/17/19 02:29:29   70           0
11/17/19 02:30:43   70           0
11/17/19 02:32:13   70           0
11/17/19 02:49:39   70           0
```

Here is the data as a dictionary, which you can use to recreate the DataFrame:

```
{'dateTime': {0: '11/17/19 02:28:05', 1: '11/17/19 02:28:17', 2: '11/17/19 02:28:31', 3: '11/17/19 02:28:42', 4: '11/17/19 02:29:29', 5: '11/17/19 02:29:46', 6: '11/17/19 02:30:43', 7: '11/17/19 02:32:13', 8: '11/17/19 02:49:39', 9: '11/17/19 02:49:49', 10: '11/17/19 02:49:54', 11: '11/17/19 02:49:59', 12: '11/17/19 02:50:04', 13: '11/17/19 02:50:09', 14: '11/17/19 02:50:14', 15: '11/17/19 02:50:24', 16: '11/17/19 02:50:29', 17: '11/17/19 02:50:34', 18: '11/17/19 02:50:39', 19: '11/17/19 02:50:44', 20: '11/17/19 02:50:49', 21: '11/17/19 02:51:04', 22: '11/17/19 02:51:09', 23: '11/17/19 03:04:05', 24: '11/17/19 03:04:33', 25: '11/17/19 11:14:27', 26: '11/17/19 11:14:42', 27: '11/17/19 11:14:52', 28: '11/17/19 11:15:01', 29: '11/17/19 11:15:06', 30: '11/17/19 11:15:21'}, 'bpm': {0: 113, 1: 70, 2: 70, 3: 70, 4: 70, 5: 70, 6: 70, 7: 70, 8: 70, 9: 67, 10: 62, 11: 57, 12: 58, 13: 60, 14: 60, 15: 62, 16: 63, 17: 65, 18: 66, 19: 67, 20: 65, 21: 66, 22: 67, 23: 69, 24: 70, 25: 70, 26: 70, 27: 70, 28: 70, 29: 70, 30: 70}, 'confidence': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1, 20: 1, 21: 1, 22: 1, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 0, 26: 0, 27: 1, 28: 1, 29: 0, 30: 1}}
```

Comment: Can you add df.to_dict() or df[0:10].to_dict() This would help with reading in the data for testing thx!

Comment: Can you create a new column with dateTime value until minute value, and then deduplicate the dataframe 
 df.drop_duplicates(subset='new column name', keep=’first’, inplace=False)

Comment: Can you share your data in a way that makes it easy for others to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we are dropping the duplicates by ignoring the seconds and take it's index values, to get original time with seconds as shown below.

```
>>> df.iloc[df['dateTime'].astype(str).str[:-2].drop_duplicates(keep='first').index,:]
```

---

**Output:**

```
            dateTime  bpm  confidence
0  11/17/19 02:28:05  113           0
4  11/17/19 02:29:29   70           0
6  11/17/19 02:30:43   70           0
7  11/17/19 02:32:13   70           0
8  11/17/19 02:49:39   70           0
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. It gave me the output that i want!

Comment: Why not use the actual time-related functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I will round seconds then check duplicates and then subset or drop duplicates of the rounded datetime

```py
df[~df['dateTime'].dt.round('min').duplicated()]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i had error when run the code. I`m still newbie so i dont the problem. Maybe because of the name 'time_dt'. Btw thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solution is the most idiomatic one, although I will keep searching.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('../resources/fitbit_time_data.csv', dtype={'bpm': np.int64, 'confidence': np.int64}, parse_dates=['date_time'], names=['date_time', 'bpm', 'confidence'], skiprows=[0])

df = df.resample(rule='min', on='date_time').first().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
            date_time    bpm  confidence
0 2019-11-17 02:28:05  113.0         0.0
1 2019-11-17 02:29:29   70.0         0.0
2 2019-11-17 02:30:43   70.0         0.0
3 2019-11-17 02:32:13   70.0         0.0
4 2019-11-17 02:49:39   70.0         0.0
```

---

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('../resources/fitbit_time_data.csv', dtype={'bpm': np.int64, 'confidence': np.int64}, parse_dates=['date_time'], names=['date_time', 'bpm', 'confidence'], skiprows=[0])

df['minute'] = df.set_index('date_time').index.minute

df = df.loc[df['minute'].shift() != df['minute']]
```

DataFrame result:

```
            date_time  bpm  confidence  minute
0 2019-11-17 02:28:05  113           0      28
4 2019-11-17 02:29:29   70           0      29
6 2019-11-17 02:30:43   70           0      30
7 2019-11-17 02:32:13   70           0      32
8 2019-11-17 02:49:39   70           0      49
```

---